# Azure and Sharepoint 2013

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013

Hi good morning I want to know if is possible to install Sharepoint 2013 on a virtual machine and if possible I have difficulty using the calculator not need to others in the database and the virtual machine to add to my calculator azure and know which is the total monthly cost of this infrastructure

Best Regards Rolando Lopez

Comment: This question might be better suited for serverfault.com ... And have you thought about [Microsoft's own Sharepoint offering/Office365](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-online-collaboration-software-FX103789366.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

there's already a image with Sharepoint Server 2013 installed.

[image]

But you can also install by yourself:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Edge/SharePoint-on-Windows-Azure

About the monthly costs, it will vary according to your usage.

Comment: how much does it cost? how can i put this in my  azure calculator and this vm has a sql server conection or sql azure conection if i need a specific size of my db how can i calculate??

Comment: can i activate the sharepoint 2013 if i have a license of sahrepoint 2013??

Comment: Yes, you can and should activate. This image has a trial version that will work up to March 17, 2014. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263204(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: You can find more info in here too: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2013/09/18/sharepoint-server-2013-enterprise-edition-trial-windows-azure-image-updated.aspx

Comment: @user3009760 I found this content that may be useful: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/MDC-B213#fbid=